# Identify the block which contains a tx

Tags: transactions, blockchain, cpp-ethereum

I am deploying a Smart Contract to a private blockchain. Is it possible to get when your node receives the smart contract? Is it possible to identify the block which contains the smart contract? how?

Comment: Have you looked at [`getTransaction()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction) from web3.js? Is there a specific tool or method you need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

Identifying when the node receives the transaction: when you are sending the transaction, most libraries implement a callback that will be called when the transaction is received by the node, but also, when the transaction has been mined, you can use once instead on on so it only executes once.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x123...', data: '0x432...'})
.once('transactionHash', function(hash){ ... })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ ... })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.then(function(receipt){
    // will be fired once the receipt is mined
});
```

Getting the block, way 1: when you send your transaction with a node, if the node accepts the transaction, it will return a transaction hash, and as Shawn pointed out you can call getTransaction() or getTransactionReceipt() (this one will return null unless it's mined) and check if the transaction has been mined and get more information about it.

```
web3.eth.getTransaction('0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b§234')
.then(console.log);

> {
    "hash": "0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b",
    "nonce": 2,
    "blockHash": "0xef95f2f1ed3ca60b048b4bf67cde2195961e0bba6f70bcbea9a2c4e133e34b46",
    "blockNumber": 3,
    "transactionIndex": 0,
    "from": "0xa94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b",
    "to": "0x6295ee1b4f6dd65047762f924ecd367c17eabf8f",
    "value": '123450000000000000',
    "gas": 314159,
    "gasPrice": '2000000000000',
    "input": "0x57cb2fc4"
}
```

Getting the block, way 2: I'd never use this one, is reading blocks all the time, and look for your transaction in them. This is by far the worst solution

```
web3.eth.getBlock(3150)
.then(console.log);

> {
    "number": 3,
    "hash": "0xef95f2f1ed3ca60b048b4bf67cde2195961e0bba6f70bcbea9a2c4e133e34b46",
    "parentHash": "0x2302e1c0b972d00932deb5dab9eb2982f570597d9d42504c05d9c2147eaf9c88",
    "nonce": "0xfb6e1a62d119228b",
    "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
    "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "transactionsRoot": "0x3a1b03875115b79539e5bd33fb00d8f7b7cd61929d5a3c574f507b8acf415bee",
    "stateRoot": "0xf1133199d44695dfa8fd1bcfe424d82854b5cebef75bddd7e40ea94cda515bcb",
    "miner": "0x8888f1f195afa192cfee860698584c030f4c9db1",
    "difficulty": '21345678965432',
    "totalDifficulty": '324567845321',
    "size": 616,
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": 3141592,
    "gasUsed": 21662,
    "timestamp": 1429287689,
    "transactions": [
        "0x9fc76417374aa880d4449a1f7f31ec597f00b1f6f3dd2d66f4c9c6c445836d8b"
    ],
    "uncles": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The deployed smart contract is not stored inside a block, but the transaction to deploy it yes. You can query that only offchain, is not available at EVM.

The smart contract (and it's storage) is contained in the "state" until it calls 'selfdestruct' (which is not be implemented in most smart contracts).